# Docker: "service" command works but "systemctl" command doesn't work

Tags: docker

I pulled **centos6** image and made a container from it. I got its bash by:

```
 $ docker run -i -t centos:centos6 /bin/bash
```

On the centos6 container, I could use "service" command without any problem. But when I pulled&used **centos7** image:

```
 $ docker run -i -t centos:centos7 /bin/bash
```

Both of "service" and "systemctl" didn't work. The error message is:

```
 Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
```

My question is:
1. How are people developing without "service" and "systemctl" commands?
2. If I want to use, for example, httpd.service on the centos7 container, what should I do? Or maybe running services on a container is not recommended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no process supervisor running inside either container.  The `service` command in your CentOS 6 container works by virtue of the fact that it just runs a script from `/etc/init.d`, which by design ultimately launch a command in the background and return control to you.

CentOS 7 uses systemd, and systemd is not running inside your container, so there is nothing for `systemctl` to talk to.

In either situation, using the `service` or `systemctl` command is generally the wrong thing to do: you want to run a single application, and you want to run it in the foreground, so that your container continues to run (from Docker's perspective, a command that goes into the background has exited, and if that was pid 1 in the container, the container will exit).

> How are people developing without "service" and "systemctl" commands?

They are starting their programs directly, by consulting the necessary documentation to figure out the appropriate command line.

> If I want to use, for example, httpd.service on the centos7 container, what should I do? Or maybe running services on a container is recommended?

You would start the `httpd` binary using something like:

```
CMD ["httpd", "-DFOREGROUND"]
```

Comment: What is the difference between CMD ["httpd", "-DFOREGROUND"] and "systemctl start httpd.service"?

Comment: `systemctl` depends on `systemd` running, which means your container must run in privileged mode and run a heavyweight daemon that is a process manager, and runs a message bus inside the container, and provides a system-level logger, and manages several kernel-level (shared outside the container) parameters, and...; and at the end once you dig down through it, `systemd` ultimately runs the same `httpd` command.

Comment: @lechat `httpd -DFOREGROUND` is running a program directly, just like running `ls` or `echo hello world`.  `systemctl start httpd.service` requires communicating with a running `systemd` process in order to make anything happen.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to stick with service/sytemctl commands to start/stop services then you can do that in a centos7 container by using the [docker-systemctl-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement) script.

I had some deployment scripts that were using th service start/stop commands on a real machine - and they work fine with a container. Without any further modification. When putting the systemctl.py script into the CMD then it will simply start all enabled services somewhat like the init-process on a real machine.

Answer (score 0):

systemd is included but not enabled by default in CentOS 7 docker image. It is mentioned on the repository page along with steps to enable it.
https://hub.docker.com/_/centos/

Comment: ...but in *almost* all cases you don't want to enable systemd (or any other process supervisor) inside your containers.

Comment: Yes, running systemd inside container actually defeats purpose of container. But if someone is inclined to run it, its their choice.